# Battlefield 4 Xbox 360 Wired Controller on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012-r2, game-controller

I'm running windows server 2012 r2 and want to use my Battlefield 4 Xbox 360 controller ([seen here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DJYTGVI)) to play games. However when I plug it in the driver does not install. I know the computer detects the device because it is listed in device manager, however device manager claims it can't find the driver for it and I can't find the driver anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not publish a driver for the XBox 360 Controller for Windows Server 2012. At the time of writing, [they offer drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-ca/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows) for Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7. It's possible that Windows 8 has built-in support for the controller.